# Log INCOMING mail to server

Tags: email, procmail

I have a mailbox on my server, mailbot, that is working fine. Mail to `mailbot@example.com` works and per the `procmailrc` file, sends back an autoresponder text file.

But I should be able to send to `mailbot+12345@example.com` and it should also be giving me a (different) autoresponder. Yet it's not.

Before I debug my autorepsonder script, I want to confirm 100% that the email message send to to `mailbot+12345@` is at least getting ON to my box. (There is a spam-capturing service that filters the mail ahead of time; they assure me that mailbot+12345@ is being passed through to my server but this is what I need to confirm.)

So I guess it's procmail that is used to receive mail (right?)... and I want to log INCOMING mail that procmail picks up, so I can see if that mail comes in.

How can I do this? I've done so much Googling and all I can find is tons of answers for how to log outgoing mail (/etc/var/maillog, yes, got it). But I want incoming. Thanks.

Comment: Which SMTP server handles incoming messages? [sendmail/postfix/exim/...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, I finally figured it out. At the top of my `.procmailrc` file, I can set a `LOG=` file to write out logging. And `VERBOSE=on` to really get a lot of logging.

Hopefully this question and answer will help someone in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, learn to read your Procmail log file.

Here's an old instruction page about exactly that:
http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html